# Storing mysql database query as a variable in C

Tags: mysql, c, unix

I'm very new to C, and have been trying to fetch a result from mysql and store it as a variable to be called later. So far I've managed to connect to my database, fetch the result and print it to the terminal. But I have no idea how to now store it as a variable. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    #include <mysql.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    main() {
    MYSQL *conn;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    char *server = "localhost";
    char *user = "root";
    char *password = ""; /* set me first */
    char *database = "develop";
    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    /* Connect to database */
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
         user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);
   }
   /* send SQL query */
   if (mysql_query(conn, "SELECT * FROM action ")) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
      exit(1);
   }
   res = mysql_use_result(conn);
   /* output table name */
   printf("MySQL Data:\n");
   while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
      printf("%s \n", row[0]);
   /* close connection */
   mysql_free_result(res);
   mysql_close(conn);
}
```

Thanks,

Liam.

Comment: So, if you print the value, how do you store the value before you print it?

Comment: @Ripwinder Do you want to save the results to a file or something?

Comment: Thats where I'm a bit stuck, I'm thinking it's stored as res before being printed to the console?? Or is it row[0]?

Comment: @Kums I want to actually call the variable later to be passed to a mobile in an NDEF message via NFC. I'm just trying to work my way through the initial steps and get an understanding of what I'm doing.

Comment: How many rows are involved here? 5? 10? a 100?

Comment: Just 1 row, it will never be more than that.

Comment: why do you need a `while` loop then? without the loop and `row = mysql_fetch_row(res)`, the variable you want is `row`.

Comment: I've removed the while loop now, so my variable is row[0]?

Answer (score 0):

The same way you would store any variable in C. You've got the hard part down since you can output your information to the console. To store the variable, assign it. In C you declare the type, name, then your SQL statement. e.g.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(char **args) {
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL *connection, mysql;
    int state;
```

Above is where the variables are declared. The part that says *result; is the PHP equivalent of $result

Below he's connecting to the database.

```
     /* connect to the mySQL database at athens.imaginary.com */
    mysql_init(&mysql);
    connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,
                                    "athens.imaginary.com",
                                    0, 0,
                                    "db_test", 0, 0);
    /* check for a connection error */
    if( connection == NULL ) {
        /* print the error message */
        printf(mysql_error(&mysql));
        return 1;
    }
    state = mysql_query(connection, 
                        "SELECT test_id, test_val FROM test");
    if( state != 0 ) {
        printf(mysql_error(connection));
        return 1;
    }
    /* must call mysql_store_result() before we can issue any
     * other query calls
     */
```

Assign the result, print the array

```
    result = mysql_store_result(connection);
    printf("Rows: %d\n", mysql_num_rows(result));
    /* process each row in the result set */
    while( ( row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL ) {
        printf("id: %s, val: %s\n", 
               (row[0] ? row[0] : "NULL"), 
               (row[1] ? row[1] : "NULL"));
    }
    /* free the result set */
    mysql_free_result(result);
    /* close the connection */
    mysql_close(connection);
```

Close the connection PHP speak: $conn = null;

```
    printf("Done.\n");
}
```

Added notes to this source: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/sql/ch13_01.htm

Comment: Thanks Stephen. If I was to call this later, what is the actual variable I should call? I think I'm so stuck in php that I just can't seem to understand. In php I would just call the $variable in say an echo statement.

Comment: @Ripwinder You're a PHP programmer. Let me find a full a full example and explain it. One sec.

Comment: @Ripwinder Found an example where they were relatively thorough. Does that make sense ish? How are you assigning variables to log?

Comment: `int main(char **args)` is not a _`C`_ signature, in any complaint compiler I know of.